# How can I check whether a stored procedure that deletes all rows from multiple tables succeeded?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I want a stored procedure that does the equivalent of the following

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Reset
AS
BEGIN
   DELETE * FROM SomeTable; 
   DELETE * FROM SomeOtherTable;
END
```

and also returns some indicator of success or failure. How would I do that? Only way I can think of is pre-calculating the number of rows that should be affected, but that seems so shoddy.

Comment: If that doesn't work (once you fix your syntax; it's just `DELETE FROM...`, not `DELETE * FROM...`) then it'll raise an error. If it doesn't raise an error then it worked. You can trust the database to do that. Though you may want to wrap the statements in a transaction to make sure it doesn't leave your data in an inconsistent state (deleted from one table but not the other) if it does fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will produce a success/failure indicator based on the question, 'did the table reset complete without failure?'.  It's wrapped in a transaction so that both deletes happen or none happen, which keeps your data clean.

```
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;
       DELETE FROM SomeTable; 
       DELETE FROM SomeOtherTable;
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
    -- success indicator
    SELECT 1 AS Result
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    -- failure indicator
    SELECT 0 AS Result
END CATCH
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what if deleting one of the tables is supposed to cascade-delete a bunch of rows in other tables. How would I check the success of that?

Comment: @Subpar, if this behavior is declared in FK definition then cascade-delete will succeed or raise an exception.